# how to configure nunjucks for custom filters with express?

Tags: javascript, express, nunjucks

I was trying to add a custom filter with nunjucks following the docs. But running the code shows output -- `Error: filter not found: my_filter_here`

These are my configurations:

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

nunjucks.configure('views', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app
})

app.set('view engine', 'html');

const env = new nunjucks.Environment();

env.addFilter('is_undefined', function(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'undefined';
});
```

For rendering templates, I am using

```js
res.render('register.html', {errors: errors});
```

in my template, I have set up like this:

```js
{% if errors|is_undefined %}
  // do something
{% endif %}
```

And this is the error I am getting: Error: `filter not found: is_undefined`

I have searched s.o before posting this question and some answers indicated that I need to use `env.render()` that I previously added the filter to instead of `res.render`. How ever when I change it to so it does not render my html page. Any solution to get things right?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to doc: [`configure` returns an Environment instance](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure). Therefore

```
const env = nunjucks.configure('views', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app
})

env.addFilter('is_undefined', function(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'undefined';
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! i can't upvote it because i have less points. can i ask more question? do i need to add `const env = new nunjucks.Environment` ?

Comment: You don't need `new nunjucks.Environment` because `nunjucks.configure` does it already.